# Reactive forms angular show error for pattern in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-custom-validators

I have reactive form like this

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(120),
        Validators.pattern('^[^\\s@]+@[^\\s@]+\\.[^\\s@]{1,}$')
      ]],
    });
```

Now I need to display error for different error, like this

```
<div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="form.controls.email.errors.pattern">THIS EMAIL NOT VALID</div>
```

But I got error
**Cannot read property 'pattern' of null**
Does anybody had similar problem with showing error for pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either fail or pass the validation. when you pass the validation `form.controls.email.errors` does not exist.

To overcome that: you need to replace **errors** with **errors?** as below:

```
<div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="form.controls.email.errors?.pattern">THIS EMAIL NOT VALID</div>
```

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pattern' of null

Answer (score -1):

Please try this ::

```
<div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="form.get('email').hasError('pattern')">THIS EMAIL NOT VALID</div>
```